How to Implement Retry Mechanism in gRPC for Node.js?
I’m trying to implement a retry mechanism in gRPC for Node.js. However, I couldn’t find any reference to Node.js in the official documentation.
Here, it's mentioned Implemented in: Java, .NET, Node, Go except hedging, and C-Core except hedging. I understand that this is based on a proposal, but this answer from 2018 mentions they were working on it. By now, the retry mechanism for Node.js should be implemented, right?
I’ve already checked the following articles and threads, but they weren’t helpful—either the answers are outdated, or there’s no response or follow-up:

gRPC with Node.js, retry mechanism?
NodeJS gRPC client is getting UNAVAILABLE without retrying

I found an example implementation for Go here, but there’s no equivalent for Node.js.
If native support for a retry mechanism isn’t available, what’s the best alternative? I’ve explored interceptors but couldn’t fully understand the implementation, maybe an example would help. I also looked into this package, but I couldn’t get it to work. Any guidance would be appreciated!
FYI: I’m using compiled JavaScript files for my proto definitions, though I’m not sure if that impacts the retry mechanism or not.
